# Dial pad implementation for reply extensions in Twilio SDK

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

I'm implementing call based application using twilio SDK and  Ract + Node.js. I have the following requirement.

During an incoming or outgoing (audio) call, a user(any user that’s using the system to call) should be able to see the number pad button.A user should be able to open a popup with the number pad and be able to press numbers. When a user uses the dial pad to press numbers the pressed numbers should be communicated to the other end.

I tried searching the documentation for related methods. found that we can use **SendDigits function** and implemented some basic logic to trigger when click on a custom button on call screen. but it seems it is not sending the data to other end.

```
const sendDigit = () => {
    console.log("Press 1");
    outboundCall.sendDigit('1');
  };
```

if anyone can guide me on how to do this would be a great help. basically, I want to have a dial pad on incoming and outgoing calls and then send press buttons according to the request by other end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a function call to `sendDigit` but [the function is called `sendDigits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#callsenddigitsdigits).

```js
const sendDigit = () => {
  console.log("Press 1");
  outboundCall.sendDigits('1');
};
```

Comment: Oh cool, glad it's sorted! If my answer helped, please do mark the answer as correct so that others can see it helped as well.